# No operator ">>" matches these operands?

Tags: c++

My program is not compiling because of this error and I am unable to solve it. I need some help.

```cpp
istream& operator>>(istream& input, const Complex& c)
{
    cout << "\nEnter real part ";
    input >> c.real;
    cout << "\nEnter img part";
    input >> c.img;
    return input;
}
```

Comment: Where is the error?.

Comment: Note that if you encounter compiler errors in future, copy/paste the _entire_ error message, including the bits that might look unreadable to you.  These are where the important information is found.  In this case, it was already obvious to a trained eye so you got away with it. ;)

Comment: In my opinion, this `operator>>` input routine is doing too much work for what an `operator>>` input routine should do.  It shouldn't be prompting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no matching operator because you cannot write to a const object.  The parameter `c` is of type `const Complex&`, meaning that `c.real` and `c.img` are read-only.  However, `operator>>` must necessarily modify them.

Remove the `const` from your function signature:

```
istream& operator>>(istream& input, Complex& c)
```